# CSS equivalent of frame="box"

Tags: css, html

I am currently doing an HTML5 unit and I can't seem to find a CSS equivalent for the HTML 4 now obsolete 
`table frame="box"`
to get a frame around the table, on all four corners
Does anyone know what the equivalent is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe `border` is what you're looking for.

```
table {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: Not equivalent, as you can see with a simple test.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela You are right, and a good answer. Practically speaking I think mine is helpful as well.

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct equivalent. The HTML 4.01 specification defines [`frame="box"`](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/tables.html#adef-frame) simply so that the frame surrounding the table is visible on all sides. It does not specify the style, color, or width of the frame, or even say that the frame corresponds to a border in CSS sense.

The [Rendering](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/rendering.html#tables) section of HTML5 CR defines the meaning of `frame="box"`, in terms of CSS. The definition is complicated as regards to combined effects of this attribute and other attributes, but basically it “is expected” to correspond to

```
border-color: black;
border-style: outset;
```

on the `table` element. It does not affect `border-width`, which is “expected to” have the default value of `2px` for a table.

In implementations, things vary. Chrome implements the attribute as causing `border-style: solid; border-width: thin` and implements `thin` as `1px`. (The color of the border is `gray` as per general defaults for `table`.) Firefox uses `border-style: outset`, but the color is defaulted to `gray` and width to `thin`, which is `1px`. IE uses a solid 1px black border; but in IE 8, the border was not solid (but `inset` I guess).

There is no way to get such varying behavior with CSS, so in practice, there is no CSS equivalent. You can, of course, specify the rendering what you *want*, using the different border properties on the `table` element, but this will not produce the same effect as `frame="box"`.

The `frame` attribute is not deprecated in HTML 4.01. The HTML5 drafts do not use the term “deprecated” at all. Instead, they declare some constructs, such as the `frame` attribute, as “obsolete”; such constructs, including this, are also defined as not being conforming, but the drafts still define them.